# Forcing HTTPS is breaking my page design

Tags: .htaccess, https, config

https is breaking my website's design. Please have a look at [www.pawpost.com.au/index.php](http://www.pawpost.com.au/index.php)

I am using opencart if that helps at all.

I have SSL 'on' in admin/system

Config file:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/admin/');
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.pawpost.com.au/ [R]
```

Any ideas on this?? It's driving me crazy.

Have tried:

1. Only with SSL 'on' in admin.
2. SSL 'on' and the config file the way it is above.
3. SSL 'on' and .htaccess the way it is above.
4. With SSL 'on', .htaccess, and config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the HTTPS links you've defined to use https:

```
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'https://www.pawpost.com.au/admin/');
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great how such small things are easily overlooked (at least by us fools).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your images reference http:// paths.  You'll need to update any paths to images and CSS files to either be a relative path or absolute path to include the https:// in it.

Comment: can I do this in my config file or .htaccess? Or must I go through every single file to manually change this?

Comment: I would personally change it.  If you have shell access, you could script it to open each file and replace http:// with https:// where ever it finds it.

Comment: Something like this might work.  (I haven't tested) [code]find . -name "*.html" -print | xargs sed -i -e 's/<http:/<https:/g'[/code]